Robert Floyd's Method to prove assignment operator
I tried this on the computer science forum and was told it was not a topic for discussion there.  I will try it here.  This is a link to the paper in question: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~necula/Papers/FloydMeaning.pdf
Please see page 23 for the section I am asking about.
I have been trying to read through Robert Floyd's Assigning Meaning to Programs but I am stuck on a bit of nomenclature.  Floyd explains how to come up with a verification condition for the assignment operation.
Given:
$P_1$ is $(x = x_0 \wedge R)$
$Q_1$ is $(x = f(x_0,\textbf{y}) \wedge R)$
$x \leftarrow f(x,\textbf{y})$ (assignment)
So if we apply Axiom 3 to $V_c(P_1;Q_1)$
we have $V_c((\exists{x})P_1; (\exists{x} Q_1)$
Then he states the following
Because $[(\exists{x}) (x = e \wedge P(x)) \equiv P(e)$
I do not understand what the $e$ is in this statement. I have tried to assume that it means edge but that doesn't seem to make any sense.

State the page number next time. It is page 23 by the way.

This is the right website for this question by the way. I don't personally know the answer with confidence but I believe e is a hypothetical variable that he made up but I might be wrong.

Updated the post to include the page number.  Thanks.
